# How to remove gap between question number and its first part?

Tags: exam

I have following text:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{-1pt}%
 }
 \renewcommand{\partshook}{%
%\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{-0pt}%
}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question \begin{parts}
\part[3] Given $f(x)=x^3-ax^2+bx+1$. If $f(2)=-3$ and $f(-1)=0$. Find the value of $a$ and $b$.
\part[2] Prove that: $\sec h^2x=1-\tan h^2x$ 
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

for which I got the output.[image]

but the desire output is:
[image]
here parts (a) and (b) are perfectly aligned.
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: The problem is caused by `\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}` and `\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}`. Just get rid of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler and gives the desired output:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question \begin{parts}
            \part[3] Given $f(x)=x^3-ax^2+bx+1$. If $f(2)=-3$ and $f(-1)=0$. Find the value of $a$ and $b$.
            \part[2] Prove that: $\sec h^2x=1-\tan h^2x$ 
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]